# Number theory divisibility problem finding infinitely many solutions of a and b

Tags: number-theory

Find infinitely many pairs of integers $a$ and $b$ with $1 < a < b$, so that $ab$ exactly divides $a^2 +b^2 −1$. Hence find all possible integer values of
$$ \frac{a^2 +b^2 −1}{ab}$$

Comment: Finding infinitely many pairs of integers $a$ and $b$ is different from finding all possible values of $ \frac{a^2 +b^2 −1}{ab}$ so which one are you asking the first question or the second?

Comment: @kingW3 both. There's 2 parts to the question

Comment: Solve this quadratic form is described by Pell equations.  Formula linking them there.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2    You must only consider all of the possible equivalent forms.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To prove that there are infinitely many solutions. Choose $a$ to be any integer greater than 1 and $b=a^2-1$.
$\frac{a^2+(a^2-1)^2-1}{a(a^2-1)} = \frac{a^4-a^2}{a(a^2-1)} = \frac{a^2(a^2-1)}{a(a^2-1)}=a$. 
This answers your second question as well.

Comment: Also of course $\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{ab}\neq 1$. All possible values are integers in $[2,+\infty)$.

Comment: probably meant this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Example_2